# Ubuntu 20.04 crashed and fails to boot "failed to start v4l2-relay daemon"

Tags: boot, 20.04

As above, the laptop froze and then rebooted but now this message flashes up for a split second and I'm left with a blinking cursor.

I've tried searching for fixes but very little results even mention the v412-relay nevermind fixing issues with it. What should I be looking at doing to get this to boot again?

---

Just to add, I can drop into the terminal at this screen but whenever I try and run anything apt related it fails with the message

```
unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
loading files list file for package 'linux-modules-ivsc-5.19.0-38-generic': cannont read /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-modules-ivsc-5.19.0-38-generic.list (input/output error)
Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

Comment: What was the last thing you did before the crash?

Comment: I'm a developer so had a few things open, the last thing I did was open a new tab in Chrome